# Use Local Variables with a DB2 Query?

Tags: sql, db2

I am trying to write a DB2 query that makes use of local variables. I really just want the query to be easier to maintain and run.

Here is the base query:

```
WITH MYTAB (CustomerId, VisitID, Sale, DateTime) 
AS ( VALUES   (1, 1, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(1, 3, 'N', '2021-04-23 21:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(2, 2, 'N', '2021-04-24 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(2, 4, 'Y', '2021-04-25 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(2, 6, 'N', '2021-04-25 23:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(3, 5, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , (
3, 7, 'N', '2021-05-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) )  

SELECT * 
FROM MYTAB A  
WHERE DateTime > '2021-04-24'
```

How would I write this same statement making use of variables? The following won't run but give the idea:

```
WITH MYTAB (CustomerId, VisitID, Sale, DateTime) 
AS ( VALUES   (1, 1, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(1, 3, 'N', '2021-04-23 21:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(2, 2, 'N', '2021-04-24 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(2, 4, 'Y', '2021-04-25 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(2, 6, 'N', '2021-04-25 23:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) , 
(3, 5, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) ,
(3, 7, 'N', '2021-05-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) )  

WITH VAR_START(STARTDTTM) AS (VALUES(DATE('2021-01-01')))  

SELECT * 
FROM MYTAB A,VAR_START 
WHERE DateTime > STARTDTTM
```

Comment: What is the environment, from where is the variable? If its from a programming language, you could use parameter binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that is what you are asking but you can have several CTE's in one query:

```
WITH MYTAB (CustomerId, VisitID, Sale, DateTime) AS  ( 
     VALUES  (1, 1, 'Y', '2021-04-23 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)     
         ,  (1, 3, 'N', '2021-04-23 21:16:00'::TIMESTAMP) 
         ,  (2, 2, 'N', '2021-04-24 20:16:00'::TIMESTAMP)
) ,  VAR_START(STARTDTTM) AS ( 
     VALUES (DATE('2021-01-01') )
)          
SELECT *  
FROM MYTAB A, VAR_START     
WHERE DateTime > STARTDTTM
```

If you want to use variables you can use an anonymous block or a stored procedure. Yet another option is to use a function that returns a table and takes a parameter as an argument.